# How is the text for closed captions and subtitles chosen for newly made, non-live TV shows?

Tags: production

I was watching Jessica Jones on Netflix and at one point the captions say `[Speaking polish]` on other shows it just seems them say something like `[Speaking foreign language]`, I was wondering just where text comes from? Does the text for newly made shows generally come from the show writers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [a Netflix blog post](http://blog.netflix.com/2012/02/update-on-captioning-for-our-members.html), they require the content provider to supply the subtitles, while creating them on their own for certain titles.

> We continue to require captions or subtitles from our providers for all new content where it is available, and we continue to author captions or subtitles for significant new content where it is missing. -Neil Hunt, Chief Product Officer.